# Can I ask questions about the meaning of the lyrics in songs?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about the meaning of the lyrics in songs on this site or for example, I heard a female vocalist on a track and I want to know who she is.

Comment: Note that these questions are on-topic at http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Both are off-topic here.

- Asking about meaning has never came up before (as far as I know). However, I can't imagine it is on-topic. If it's the English itself or the meaning of a phrase that you don't understand, try it on [English Language & Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).
- Asking about who the vocalist is is explicitly off-topic per the [FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/faq) (it falls under the identification section).

I appreciate you asking on meta first (I feel a little bad when I vote to close a user's first question).

Comment: As I speak, I've just voted to close a new user's first post because he failed to check the FAQ. :(

Comment: Maybe a notice that shows up on a users first post, "Here are questions we answer...". Then you wouldn't feel bad... :P

Comment: The site is music.stackexchange.com. If you cannot ask questions about music then it should not have the URL music.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is a site for musicians. Our topics include practice & performance technique, music theory, notation, history, composition, instrument maintenance, and usage of specific music software. This is how it stands now. I see you've raised [another post](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/435/1678). We'll see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I'm a musician too!